$\rm N_2O$ for tire inflation
I have a car with slightly underinflated tires, and I'm seeking out an overcomplicated solution. Let's get that out of the way first!
What's happened is my car started reporting worse fuel economy, and as a part of my troubleshooting process I found that the local service stations have poorly calibrated equipment and my tire pressures are incorrect. I've learned how inaccurate even high-quality, high price inflation equipment is (See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vHfv9FoPQnY ). I bought one of the low-cost pressure gauges that performed well in the video test, and confirmed the low pressure.
I had been thinking about getting a compressed nitrogen (N2) gas cylinder and to using that to top up my tires at home. The gas is somewhat readily available for welding and diving. The only problems with N2 are:

It is distributed in compressed gas form and not liquid, so there's always going to be much less usable product than a gas provided in liquid form;
Anything rated for N2 is grossly overpriced, because of the impression that N2 is used by aviation and racing so it's a "luxury" product if used for inflation. (pure N2 appears to be used because the lack of water in the tires prevents water phase changes that grossly change tire pressures across temperature differentials)

Meanwhile, CO2 can be had for a low price from bicycle supply chains, but I've read cautions about the chemical action of CO2 (e.g. decomposing to carbonic acid and damaging wheels) and CO2's physical properties (leaking out faster, or dissolving into the rubber).
So this brings me to another readily available gas, N2O. I see the cartridges discarded at the end of my street on a weekly basis. I know they are available for food service use as well as a vehicle combustable. Also these molecules are large, presumably as (or more) resistant to leaking out than N2 molecules. Further thoughts:

Like CO2, N2O is distributed in liquid form I believe. So I could buy one cylinder and it would last longer than the same storage profile as N2.
N2O might be dangerous in a fire, possibly providing a burst of oxygen if tires burst in a fire in excess of 500˚C (is that really a risk?)
N2O is a greenhouse gas, would be much worse than N2 to release.

Just wondering if anybody has thoughts on N20 as a tire inflation gas.

Wow! That's a good insight I guess, but not a question suitable for SE.

Is it unsuitable because my question is simply whether anybody has any thoughts? I could probably be more precise... asking whether there's any data on permeability.

It isn't really a physics question. E.G. It isn't about properties of N$_2$O. It is more of an engineering question. Applications of physics to solve a problem.

Yh, hope you understand.

Nitrous oxide isn't inert, it's an oxidizing agent. So it may react with some component of the tyre.

Engineering it is! Yes, I'm looking for the convergence of safety, molecular physical properties, and chemical properties. Thank you.

Nitrogen isn't totally safe, particularly in liquid form. For example, LN$_2$ boils rapidly and can replace the air in the room. You don't smell it. You just pass out if there isn't enough oxygen.

For what it is worth,  if you buy tires from Costco they are inflated with nitrogen, and Costco claims that they will top them for free  for the life of the tire. l  have my own compressor, so I have not tried N$_2$.

@mmesser314 I think N2 for use in tires is really just compressed air, with a scrubber to remove O2 and H2O. The devices that supply N2 are not cryogenic, they are just a compressed air tank with a filter that needs to be changed periodically.

I doubt there is any value to using N$_2$ in tires. The idea is that oxygen degrade to rubber. Even if you use N$_2$ on the inside, the outside is not protected. And when you put a tire on the rim, it is full of air. You then pressurize it with N$_2$. Still lots of oxygen inside. Finally, tires inflated with N$_2$ have a green cap. Gas stations that don't provide N$_2$ will refuse to inflate your tires. Running on low pressure until you get back to your home station is worse that having oxygen inside.

@mmesser314 disagree with a lot of your claims. My car has "N2" printed on the valve caps, but they are silver, not green. The tires have Shrader valves and I can fill them with compressed air available anywhere. The tire shop also did not mention the N2 issue.
Most importantly however, I am not proposing to fill my tires with N2. I am proposing N2O.

One tank of N2 should last for quite a few tires. If you truly need it on an industrial scale, you can buy a dewar and store as much LN2 as you could conceivably need. Tanks come up to swimming pool size or larger. Evan a small dewar is not worth it unless you are using it at a high rate. There is boil off.
If you don't want to keep buying LN$_2$, you can buy a refrigerator to make your own. Or if you really want to over complicate things, make your own refrigerator.

Ohhh, generating my own N2. That just might be worth installing electricity in the garage! Thank you.

However, the engineer in me says, if I generate my own icy cold N2 it's going to get water ice contamination almost immediately. As that's the whole point of a compressed air replacement, I don't think I could do it.

Liquid nitrogen is less dense than water ice, so any water contamination will solidify, sink to the bottom of the liquid, and stay there until the nitrogen has all boiled away. Liquid nitrogen boils to make dry nitrogen.  It is possible to get a little film of liquid oxygen of the surface of the nitrogen — but if you're interested in the dry nitrogen vapor boiling off of the liquid, the liquid oxygen is a contaminant that has been removed from the gas phase.
